# Cannot export cmake PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR because it equals zero

Tags: c++, cmake, versioning

I'm having trouble with exporting cmake `PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR` variable to the `config.h` file. In my main `CMakeLists.txt` I'm setting this variable according to the cmake documentation by invoking `project()` in main `CMakeLists.txt` file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2.2)
cmake_policy(SET CMP0048 NEW)

set(PROJECT "SampleName")

project(${PROJECT}
    VERSION "0.0.0")

configure_file(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/config.h.cmake ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/config.h)
```

Through `configure_file()` invokation I'm trying to export some cmake variables to the `config.h` header file.Please take a look on my `config.h.cmake.file`:

```
#ifndef CONFIG_H
#define CONFIG_H

#cmakedefine PROJECT "@PROJECT@"

#cmakedefine PROJECT_VERSION "@PROJECT_VERSION@"

#cmakedefine PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR "@PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR@"

#cmakedefine PROJECT_VERSION_MINOR "@PROJECT_VERSION_MINOR@"

#cmakedefine PROJECT_VERSION_PATCH "@PROJECT_VERSION_PATCH@"

#endif
```

After running `cmake ..` command in my build directory `config.h` is created but it look like this:

```
#ifndef CONFIG_H
#define CONFIG_H

#define PROJECT "SampleName"

#define PROJECT_VERSION "0.0.0"

/* #undef PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR */

/* #undef PROJECT_VERSION_MINOR */

/* #undef PROJECT_VERSION_PATCH */

#endif
```

I guess reason of this behaviour is following note in cmake documentation for the `configure_file()` function:

> Copies an  file to an  file and substitutes variable
>   values referenced as `@VAR@` or `${VAR}` in the input file content. Each
>   variable reference will be replaced with the current value of the
>   variable, or the empty string if the variable is not defined.
>   Furthermore, input lines of the form:
>
> `#cmakedefine VAR ..`.
>
> will be replaced with either:
>
> `#define VAR ...`
>
> or:
>
> `/* #undef VAR */`
>
> depending on whether `VAR` is set in CMake to **any value not considered a**
>   **false constant by the `if()` command**. The `”...”` content on the line
>   after the variable name, if any, is processed as above. Input file
>   lines of the form `#cmakedefine01 VAR` will be replaced with either
>   `#define VAR 1` or `#define VAR 0` similarly.

The question is, can I export cmake `PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR` variable which equals zero ? Or am I doomed for parsing my `PROJECT_VERSION` define in my code ?

After applying advice from hank, newly generated file looks like this:

```
#ifndef CONFIG_H
#define CONFIG_H

#define PROJECT "SampleName"

#define PROJECT_VERSION "0.0.0"

#define PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR "0"

#define PROJECT_VERSION_MINOR "0"

#define PROJECT_VERSION_PATCH "0"

#endif
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think in your case you should not use `#cmakedefine` directive. Use simple `#define` instead:

```
#ifndef CONFIG_H
#define CONFIG_H

#define PROJECT "@PROJECT@"

#define PROJECT_VERSION "@PROJECT_VERSION@"

#define PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR "@PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR@"

#define PROJECT_VERSION_MINOR "@PROJECT_VERSION_MINOR@"

#define PROJECT_VERSION_PATCH "@PROJECT_VERSION_PATCH@"

#endif
```

Comment: @Lazureus As documentation, can you share how the generated file looks like (As an appendix to your question)

Comment: @Antonio, I've added newly generated file for you, please take a look in the answer.

Comment: Indeed thte documentation says it will do replacement wether we use cmakedefines or not. My understanding is we use cmakedefines it to add comment when variable is not defined ( /* #undef VAR */). I did not catched that.